# How to hide keyboard when you select UIPickerView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have a DatePicker where the user selects time and date fields, the keyboard shows up first and then I have to click the textfield again for the Picker to appear. What I want is for the DatePicker to show up on the first try.

here is my code

```
@IBOutlet var dateField: UITextField! = UITextField()

@IBOutlet var timeField: UITextField! = UITextField()

@IBAction func userPickDate(sender: UITextField) {

    var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    sender.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

}
  @IBAction func userPickTime(sender: UITextField) {

    var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
    sender.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleTimePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

}

   func handleTimePicker(sender: UIDatePicker)
{
    var timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    timeField.text = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)

}



func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
    //timeFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    dateField.text = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discard the last answer. I understood whAT you are doing. Here is what I found: Placing the declaration of the UPickerView objects in the scope of the class rather than localized to the handler seemed to work. Here is the code. Note the addition of the resignFirstResponder().

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    var timePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    @IBOutlet weak var dateField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    dateField.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    handleDatePicker(datePickerView)


    timePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
    timeField.inputView = timePickerView
    timePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleTimePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    handleTimePicker(timePickerView)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
    //timeFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    dateField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    dateField.resignFirstResponder()

}

func handleTimePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    var timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    timeField.text = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    timeField.resignFirstResponder()

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks! this really helped. For the most part it works but when i drag the picker for one of the columns (example month) it instantly closes without me picking the day and year, i want to be able to choose everything, so i deleted the resignFirstResponder and used  touchesBegan func

Comment: do you know how to make it so that the date and time it is on is selected without having to change it then change it back (when you basically want to use the current date and time )

Comment: You are right about the behavior. Your approach is reasonable to fix it (I have not tried it). You can fix the second problem by inserting handleDatePicker(datePickerView) and handleTimePicker(timePickerView) in viewDidLoad.

Comment: how would i insert those functions in the view did load?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place an action on your textField as such:

```
    @IBAction func userDOBSelectedAction(sender: UITextField) {
    userDOBTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an updated version of Syed's answer for Swift 2.2 & includes some formatting updates.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    var timePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    @IBOutlet weak var dateField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        datePickerView.datePickerMode = .Date
        dateField.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleDatePicker(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        handleDatePicker(datePickerView)

        timePickerView.datePickerMode = .Time
        timeField.inputView = timePickerView
        timePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleTimePicker(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        handleTimePicker(timePickerView)
    }

    func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
        dateField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
        dateField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func handleTimePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
        timeField.text = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
        timeField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```